# Extracting Data from large table / array. using VBA excel

Tags: excel, find, row, extract, vba

How can I extract a row of data based upon a search criteria in column 1, for example, from a table or array (I believe that because im using large amounts of data - 40k-200k - that an array option would be faster)

Code needed

1. Find specified data in sheet1 - column 1. this specified data is a list of names
2. Extract the row containing that data (e.g column 1 2 3 4)
3. Past the row(s) into new table
4. Repeat to find next

**Example**
user wants to search for people aged 23 and 25 (/ indicates new column) which has been defined in sheet2 cell A1 and A2 (or in an array)

Name / Gender / Age / Height /
Bob   / M      / 23  / 6.1    /
Fred / M      / 23  / 6.0    /
Gill / f      / 25 /  6.3    /
garry/ M      / 29  / 5.3    /
adam / M      / 27  / 5.9   /
amy  / f      / 23  / 6.2    /

**Results**

Bob   / M      / 23  / 6.1    /
Fred / M      / 23  / 6.0    /
Gill / f      / 25 /  6.3    /
amy  / f      / 23  / 6.2    /

Any assistance would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can usually be done with AutoFilter.  Establish the criteria on the fields of interest; then copy the visible rows; then paste the rows or partial rows elsewhere.

This can be done manually or via macro.

You can also use macros to avoid AutoFilter entirely and hide rows based on arbitrary criteria that AutoFilter may not support.

For on-line info, see: [AutoFilter Description](http://www.contextures.com/xlautofilter01.html)